# Load images from sdcard in grid with Picasso

Tags: android, image, android-sdcard, picasso

I have a grid that has string arraylist of items:

```
    final GridView grid = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    final ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

    items.add("1a");
    items.add("1b");
    items.add("1c");
    items.add("1d");
    items.add("1e");
    items.add("2a");
    items.add("2b");
    items.add("2c");
    items.add("2d");
    items.add("2e");
    items.add("3a");
    items.add("3b");
    items.add("3c");
    items.add("3d");
    items.add("3e");
    items.add("3f");
    items.add("4a");
    items.add("4b");
    items.add("4c");
    items.add("4d");
    items.add("4e");
    items.add("4f");
    items.add("4g");
```

Later, I tried to do something with onClick, selecting a certain position:

```
 grid.setAdapter(new GridAdapter(items));

        grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                  if(position == 3)
                      ...
            }
        });
```

What I would like is:

I have like 20 pictures in my `res/drawable` folder. I'd like to have a fragment that contains an imageView, that runs on onClick, and loads picture named 1a.png into item 1a, 1b.png into item 1b and so forth, without having selecting certain positions.

So when I click on 1a in gridview, it displays 1a.png, 1b displays 1b.png and so forth...

Thanks.

Comment: Then what problem you are getting ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I couldn't find a way to do it. I couldn't get 1a to load 1a.png, 1b to load 1b.png without having to use if statements with positions.

Answer (score 0):

Because `ArrayList` list contains all names of images with is in `res/drawable` folder. so no need to use `if-else` and `witch-case` for getting image according to clicked item in GridView:

**1.** Send clicked item name on `onItemClick` to next Activity in which want to show selected image using Intent. like:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
     String selectedImage = grid.getItemAtPosition(position);
     // prepare Intent for starting next Activity:

     Intent intent=new Intent(....);
     intent.putExtra("selectedImage", selectedImage);
     // start next Activity or Fragment....
  }
```

**2.** In next Activity get image name from Intent and use `getIdentifier` to get drawable id using name in onCreate method:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String selectedImage = intent.getStringExtra("selectedImage");
int identifier = getResources().getIdentifier(selectedImage, 
                                    "drawable",getPackageName());
```

Pass `identifier` in `setImageResource` method of ImageView to show selected image.